# Where do you put hints when you send back 400 HTTP Status for a specific error?

Tags: http

How do you give any hints with a 400 status code?
For example, I know that I will throw a 400 if a certain cookie is missing or empty. Do I put a message in the body? In some "Error hint" header?

Thank you

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into the content. You may want to look at RFC 7807, "Problem Details for HTTP APIs".

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn’t find this RFC. It’s perfect.